# Evaluating Confidence Interval for difference of sample mean of two random variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have two normally distributed populations X and Y that have the same variance and are independent. I took two samples from X and Y and got the following:

For $X:\; n = 10,\; \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i = 78,\; 
\sum_{i=1}^{10} = 634.$

[For x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6di8j.png)

For $Y:\; n = 8,\; \sum_{i=1}^8 Y_i = 36,\; 
\sum_{i=1}^6 = 184.$

[For Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eouk1.png)

Now I need to build a confidence interval with 98% probability for the difference of the means.

---

I understand that because the sample is not large, I will need to use t-student distribution. My question is how to find the standard deviation to use in the confidence interval formula considering I only have the sum of $X_i$ and the sum of the $X_iˆ2.$

Shall I use that $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2?$

Comment: Welcome to the site. // Please use JaX to format mathematical notation instead of posting pictures. // No, the variance formula you give at the end is for random variables with known distributions, not for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get you started on this by showing you how to compute the required *sample* standard deviations, pointing you to the formulas for the CI, and showing you the CI I got from software.

**Formulas for sample variance.** The sample variance for the $X_i$ can be obtained from
the following formula:

$$S^2_x = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2}{n-1}
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac 1n(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2}{n-1}\\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\bar X^2}{n-1}.$$
Take the square root of the sample variance to get the sample standard deviation.

**Sample means and standard deviations for your data.** Using R as a calculator: The sample mean (average) of the first sample is $\bar X = 7.8$

```
a.x = 78/10;  a.x
[1] 7.8
```

and (using the formula above) the sample standard deviation of the first sample is $S_x = 1.6865.$

```
s.x = sqrt((634-(78)^2/10)/(10-1));  s.x
[1] 1.686548

sqrt((634-10*(7.8)^2)/(10-1))
[1] 1.686548   # alternate method
```

Similarly, for the second sample: $\bar Y = 4.5$ and
$S_y = 1.7728.$

```
a.y = 36/8;  a.y
[1] 4.5

s.y = sqrt((184-(36)^2/8)/(8-1));  s.y
[1] 1.772811
```

**Finding the CI for the difference in population means.** Now you are ready to find the formulas for the pooled
estimate of the common population standard deviation
and the formula for a confidence interval of the
difference $\mu_x - \mu_y$ in *population* means.

Instead of doing these computations here, I put sample sizes, means, and standard deviations into a recent release of Minitab in order to get the 95% CI for the difference
in population means from Minitab's pooled t test procedure.
Results below:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       10  7.80   1.69     0.53
2        8  4.50   1.77     0.63

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  3.300
95% CI for difference:  (1.566, 5.034)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
  T-Value = 4.03  P-Value = 0.001  DF = 16
Both use Pooled StDev = 1.7248
```

The difference in *sample* means is $\bar X = \bar Y$ $= 7.80 - 4.50$ $= 3.30,$ which is the center of your 95% CI for the difference in *population* means $(1.566, 5.034),$ which also uses the
pooled estimate $S_p = 1.7248$ of the common
population standard deviation. (The pooled method
assumes that the two populations have the same
standard deviation.)

*Note:*  The methods above are correct, but please proofread my typing, data entry, and computations.